# unable to target specific css class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

trying to target `.product-price on-sale` to change the color to green but i'm not able to.

HTML

```
<h2 id="product-price" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
  <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />
  <span class="product-price on-sale" itemprop="price">$ 1</span>&nbsp;<del class="product-compare-price"></del>
</h2>
```

CSS

```
section#buy h2.product-price-on-sale span {
   color:green  !important;
}
```

Comment: `span.product-price.on-sale { ... }` should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problems with your selector:

> section#buy h2.product-price-on-sale span

- First part:

  > section#buy

  It's ok assuming you have an extra wrapper with id `buy`

  ```
  <section id="buy">
  ```
- Second part

  > h2.product-price-on-sale

  Wrong since element `h2` doesn't have a classname of `product-price-on-sale` instead has an id `product-price`, must be at this point:

  > section#buy h2#product-price
- Third part:

  > span

  It's ok since the `span` element is inside the `h2`, but if you want to target the one with class `product-price` and `on-sale` your final selector must be:

  > section#buy h2#product-price span.product-price.on-sale

Answer (score 2):

With reference to your code this should work:

```
h2#product-price span.product-price.on-sale{
 color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS selector is wrong because your `.product-price-on-sale` class is on your `span` element not your `h2`.  It should be

```
section#buy h2 .product-price.on-sale {
    color:green  !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`class="product-price on-sale"`
`... h2.product-price-on-sale`

You wrote it as two classes in the html and as one class in css (space vs dash).
The css for two class selection is `.class1.class2`.

You also are not targeting the right tag, as pointed by other answers.